# Why resistors consumes power?

Tags: electric-circuits, energy-conservation, electric-current, electrical-resistance, dissipation

[image]

this is a basic voltage divider circuit. Whenever electrons are about to enter in $R_2$ they have some energy. And when they leave R_2 their energy level decreases.

1. what kind of energy we are talking about? is it kinetic energy? if that is the case then why it looses that? it should not loose because the electric field is uniform everywhere in the wire and hence in the resistor , so same amount of force is being applied all the time by the electric field on each electron. Is this because while passing through a resistive path, the net force acting on an electron decreases, so the velocity of the electron decreases and hence the kinetic energy reduces?

Answer (score 3):

Take a lead sphere and let it fall in honey under the influence of gravitation. The gravitational force is constant but honey is so viscous that the sphere will barely accelerates and its velocity is almost constant, and so is the case of electrons despite the presence of a constant electric field intensity. In case of electric conduction it is not friction that slows the electrons down but rather their random collisions with the ions of the metal. Every time an electron hits the crystal it shakes that up a bit while losing some of its kinetic energy will excite some phonons and warms up the metal, the Joule heat.